# How do I force a gradle dependency for a specific sub-project?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

This is what it is doing:

```
org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.5.7 -> 2.0.2
```

Just for this sub-project, I want to force 1.5.7. BTW this thing is buried pretty deep. There has to be a better way than peeling the onion to get at the one dependency for an exclude. I mean if I have a dependency X why can't I programatically cascade down the tree doing the exclude? This is Gradle, right?

This almost worked:

```
configurations {

    compile.resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.5.7'
    }
...
}
```

The above shows up correctly in the tree but 2.0.2 still winds up in the War.

Regardless anyway that is effective and doesn't require digging it out manualy, I'll take.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `force` you might consider using `substitute`.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.1'
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        // add dependency substitution rules
        dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module('org.apache.santuario:xmlsec') with module('org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:1.5.7')
        }
    }
}
```

Then I get an output of:

```
$ ./gradlew -q dependencies --configuration compile

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

compile - Dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- org.apache.santuario:xmlsec:2.0.1 -> 1.5.7
     \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
```

Comment: I'll give it a try but it didn't seem like if one didn't work the other would... but who knows, right?